# Treating an array of bools as though incrementing in binary

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, binary

I'm trying to create a loop that changes the values in a boolean array so that it looks like the array is incrementing in binary values.

For example

```
1st iteration [0|0|0]
2nd iteration [0|0|1]
3rd iteration [0|1|0]
4th iteration [0|1|1]
```

etc.

This array is dynamic, however, and can be different sizes. So whatever loop I write would need to also work on an array with five elements instead of three.

Apologies for not having any starting code, but I've been frustrating myself with this for hours and still can't even come up with how to begin.

Comment: Write something similar, but simpler then.  Write a loop that just iterates arrays of size 1.  Then try 3.  Then try n.  "I can't possibly begin anything" is not very believable.

Comment: Just do it the same way, you have learned addition of large numbers in school (colon by colon and carry over)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://ideone.com/SxL38k). This may not be complete but you could do something similar

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void increment(bool* array, int len)
{
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if ( ! array[i])
        {
            array[i] = true;
            return;
        }
        array[i] = false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool* array = new bool[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        increment(array, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            cout << (array[i] ? 1 : 0) << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code isn't dependent on the line `cout << (array[i] ? 1 : 0)`, right? It still stores all the necessary values, and then that just outputs true if `array[i]` is true and false if `array[i]` is false? And the return in the if statement just iterates the for loop, doesn't exit the function? I actually need to return a value in my function

Comment: Nested array in main() is only for displaying values. increment() function is is separated for clarity. You can take that to the main() itself. Then replace return with break.

Comment: Would adding the for loop `for(int i = 0; i < len;i++)` accomplish what the for loop in main is doing (10 times instead of 5 in this case)? Then printing could be done separately. For some reason, when I try to separate the printing and the incrementing, the increment function stops working.

Comment: try this which doesn't have a separate function. You need to print in each iteration to get the state after each iteration.  http://ideone.com/SxL38k

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void ArrayIterate(int);
void printArray(bool*,int);

void ArrayIterate(int arraySize)
{
    int decimal_value = 0;
    int decimal_place_value = 0;
    bool* boolArray = new bool(arraySize);
    long double max_itr = pow(2,arraySize);
    for (int i = 0; i < max_itr ; ++i)
    {
        decimal_value = i;
        // set array values
        for ( int k = arraySize - 1; k >= 0; --k)
        {
            decimal_place_value = pow(2,k);
            if( decimal_value != 0 && decimal_value / decimal_place_value >= 1 )
            {
                boolArray[k] = true;
                decimal_value -= decimal_place_value;
            }
            else
                boolArray[k] = false;
        }
        printArray(boolArray,arraySize);
        cout << " = " << i << endl; ;
    }
    delete boolArray;
    return;
}

void printArray(bool* boolArray, int arraySize)
{
    cout << "\t";
    for(int i = arraySize - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        cout << ((boolArray[i] == true)? 1 : 0) << " ";
    return;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "\n\n";
    ArrayIterate(4); 
    cout << "\n\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```